# ajax call not working when converted from getJSON in Amcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, amcharts

This is the ajax call method in the javascript file to plot the bar graph in Amcharts.

bar.js

```
plot_graph();

function plot_graph(){

$.ajax({ 


    url:back+"/cool?day=30",

    type: "GET",
    dataformat: "JSON",



    success: function(data){
        alert("succes while plotting down graph");

        var amc=AmCharts.makeChart("plot",
                {
            "type": "serial",

              "dataSets": [{
                "dataProvider": data,
                "categoryField": "time"
              }],
            "categoryField": "name",
            "startDuration": 1,
            "categoryAxis": {
                "gridPosition": "start"
            },
            "trendLines": [],
            "graphs": [
                {
                    "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]]",
                    "fillAlphas": 0.8,
                    "lineAlpha": 0.2,
                    "id": "AmGraph-1",
                    "title": "Bar Graph",
                    "type": "column",
                    "valueField": "tips",
                    "color":"#6fdc6f"
                },
                {
                    "balloonText": "[[title]] of [[category]]:[[value]] k",
                    "fillAlphas": 1,
                    "id": "AmGraph-2",
                    "title": "Distance",
                    "type": "column",
                    "valueField": "mile"
                }
            ],
            "guides": [],
            "valueAxes": [
                {
                    "id": "ValueAxis-1",
                    "title": "Milage",
                    "gridColor": "#FFFFFF",
                    "gridAlpha": 0.2

                }
            ],
            "gridAboveGraphs": true,
            "allLabels": [],
            "balloon": {},
            "legend": {
                "enabled": true,
                "useGraphSettings": true
            },
            "titles": [
                {
                    "id": "Title-1",
                    "size": 15,
                    "text": " Cool"
                }
            ]

        });

      },
    error:function(){

        alert("error while plotting down graph");

    }  
    });
```

}

But when I access the webservice api it shows the data and the alert box appears with "succes while plotting down graph".But the plot is not plottting.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dataSets` is a stock chart property, not a serial chart property (note your chart `type`). You need to set the `dataProvider` instead and set the `categoryField` in the top level of the configuration:

```
var amc = AmCharts.makeChart("plot", {
  // ...
  "dataProvider": data,
  "categoryField": "time",
  // ..
});
```

Note that only one categoryField is allowed, not two.